# How to add custom Springdoc resources to swagger-ui page

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox, springdoc

I'm not good at swagger and related libraries, so sorry if the title is confusing.

I have several services which provide their api as swagger documentation in json format and via swagger-ui. Next, I have a springboot service which is a proxy of the previously mentioned services and it provides combined api of all services (one can select exact service in a dropdown). It was implemented like this:

```
public class PropertyResourceProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {
  @Autowired
  private SwaggerConfigProperties swaggerConfigProperties; // Just a mapping of config

  @Override
  public List<SwaggerResource> get() {
    // Doc for local (proxy) service
    val local = new SwaggerResource();
    local.setName(title);
    local.setUrl(swaggerLocal);
    local.setSwaggerVersion(version);

    // Add other services - specified in config
    List<SwaggerResource> services = swaggerConfigProperties.getServices().stream().map(service -> {
      String contextPath = service.get("contextPath");
      String externalPath = SWAGGER_DOC_BASE_PATH + "/" + contextPath;

      val resource = new SwaggerResource();
      resource.setName(service.get("name"));
      resource.setUrl(externalPath);
      resource.setSwaggerVersion(service.get("version"));

      return resource;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    services.add(local);

    return services; // Return combined API
  }
```

Now, we're moving from springfox to springdoc and I can't use SwaggerResource and SwaggerResourcesProvider. How can I implements the same using springdoc?

Comment: This article may be useful: https://wstutorial.com/rest/rest-api-documentation-springdoc.html